For the same amount of thrust, is a jet airplane quieter than a propeller airplane?
If you have two airplanes, one generating thrust directly with a jet engine, and the other generating thrust with a propeller (from any of its power sources i.e: ICE/piston, electric, etc), which one is quieter?

It's hard to compare because the bulk of the noise from a turboprop will be around 60-100 Hz and will be dominant, while the jet engine will tend to be high intensity white noise (or partial white noise).  I think people perceive turboprops as being louder than jets.

The propeller driven aeroplane is quieter: it accelerates a higher mass at a lower velocity.
Aircraft thrust  is given as $ = \dot{m} \cdot (V_e - V_c)$, with

$\dot{m}$ = accelerated air mass flow in kg/s;
$V_e$ = average exhaust gas velocity;
$V_c$ = cruise speed.

Picture below is from this answer, which shows the difference in noise between a low bypass and a high bypass jet engine. The difference is caused by the engine on the right accelerating a higher flow to a lower velocity in order to obtain the same thrust, by means of its larger bypass fan. And a propeller is nothing more than an even larger bypass fan...


I agree with the logic but I’m not certain that a comparison between two engines with enclosed fans can be extended to an open-propeller engine.

Unfortunately, this answer misses the elephant in the room: With a propeller, you have a low count of blades at low rotation speed, where each blade's low/high pressure zone sends out a single crest/trough of a very strong sound wave. In principle, a turbine generates sound waves in the same way, but at much, much higher frequencies, easily going into the totally inaudible ultrasound range.

Another point is that the free blade ends of a propeller will generate strong vortices, which a shrouded impeller avoids entirely. So, reducing this question to the amount of air moved is a misleading oversimplification.

I don't believe this factors in noise from the piston engine either, does it?

There is noise, then again, there is vibration
